# Does anyone know how to hide the client_id and client_secret on Available authorizations dialog in Swagger SwashBuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm allowing customers to access my SaaS API via Swashbuckle. They are required to authenticate using OAuth via the Available authorizations popup. When they click the Authorize button via the popup they are required to authenticate via gmail. However, this shows the Auth0 client_id and client_secret SwashBuckle uses which I need hidden from the end user.

Does anyone know if there's a way for this to be hidden?

I've attached a screenshot to this question.

My code in AddSwaggerGen contains the following

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "oauth2",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
    {
        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(settings.AuthorityAuthorizeUri),
            TokenUrl = new Uri(settings.AuthorityTokenUri),
        }
    },
    Scheme = "oauth2"
});

c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Bearer {token}\"",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Scheme = "Bearer"
});

c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description = "Standard Authorization header using the ApiKey scheme. Example: \"ApiKey {ClientId:ClientSecret}\". Please note the prefix \"ApiKey\" is required!",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Scheme = "ApiKey"
});


c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "oauth2"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "oauth2",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

        },
        new List<string>()
    },
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            },
            Scheme = "ApiKey",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

        },
        new List<string>()
    },
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "ApiKey"
            },
            Scheme = "ApiKey",
            Name = "ApiKey",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
```

And my code in UseSwaggerUI contains

```
c.OAuthClientId(config["ClientId"]);
c.OAuthClientSecret(config["ClientSecret"]);
c.OAuthAppName("blah");
c.OAuthScopeSeparator(string.Empty);
var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
param.Add("audience", "blah");
param.Add("scope", "openid profile email");
c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(param);
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us your swagger configuration

Comment: Hi @RomanMarusyk I just updated my question with snippets of the relevant code.

Comment: Maybe inject some CSS that can hide that

Answer (score 1):

I know this is perhaps old but this worked for me.
One can hide the fields with css.
Taken from this great post [OAuth PKCE flow for ASP.NET Core with Swagger](https://www.camiloterevinto.com/post/oauth-pkce-flow-for-asp-net-core-with-swagger)

See this part

```
app.UseSwagger()
.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    // ...        
    options.InjectStylesheet("/content/swagger-extras.css");
});
```

and the css

```
.auth-container .wrapper {
display: none;
}
```